Simple random walk "relatively short" time scales
Consider the symmetric random walk $S_n$ on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ (since I mostly care about 2-dims, but probably holds for all dimensions).
By the local central limit theorem (LCLT), we know that the probability the RW hits $x \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ starting from $0$ in $n$ steps is given by
$$
\mathbb{P}_0[S_n=x] =\frac{2}{\pi n}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{n}\right) +O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
$$
In the limit of $n\to \infty$.
But what if I want to consider "small" $n$ relative large $x$ (i.e., $\sqrt{n} \ll ||x||_2$), what would be the asymptotic limit? For example, using Chebyshev, one can show that
$$
\mathbb{P}_0[S_n =x] \le C\exp \left(-c\frac{||x||_2}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
$$
(for some constants $C,c>0$)
But can we do better? Can we do something like
$$
\mathbb{P}_0[S_n =x] \le C\frac{1}{n}\exp \left(-c\frac{x^2}{n}\right)
$$
(for some constants $C,c>0$)

What is $x$ in a two-dimensional random walk? A point in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ or a distance from $0$?  Are you interested in the position after $n$ steps or the time of the first hit, or of hitting within $n$ steps?

You could try using bounds related to Stirling's approximation, e.g. (26) from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html (see also the Wikipedia page for Stirling's approximation)

How would that approximation go roughly? Are you counting paths?

Something is wrong in your right hand side expressions: what does $\exp(-x/\sqrt{n})$ even mean when $x \in \mathbb{Z}^2$? Do you mean to write $\exp(-|x|_2/\sqrt{n})$?
